# Angular ui-select tagging on array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, tags, ui-select

**SITUATION:**

I have an angular app that sends emails. 
There are three fields: Address - Subject - Text. 
The address field is built using angular [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

The email address can be choosen from the list or entered anew.
The problem is entering the new email address.

I am trying to use the tagging property to obtain it.
But as far as i can see is working only when the ui-select is made of an array of simple strings and not when is made of an array of objects

**CODE:**

```
<h3>Array of objects</h3>
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="new tag" ng-model="multipleDemo.selectedPeople" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small>
      email: {{person.email}}
      age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.selectedPeople}}</p>
```

**PLUNKER:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/nngkvjiQmI44smcNGRGm?p=preview

As you can see it is working properly for simple strings array and not with objects array

**QUESTION:**

How can i use the tagging in ui-select with array of objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have missing function name in the **tagging** attribute.

try

> tagging="tagTransform"

and then add tagTransform function in the controller scope

```
$scope.tagTransform = function (newTag) {
  var item = {
     name: newTag,
     email: newTag+'@email.com',
     age: 'unknown',
     country: 'unknown'
   };
   return item;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7fSAKmj3pLeeTaid4pMH?p=preview

Comment: For what it's worth. Yes, it can be done by setting: tagging-label="false". Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/983